# How do the twitter/facebook ios apps mark last read location?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, twitter

I've been trying to figure this out with google/looking through the apple developer info and searching here, but can't work it out.

In the current Twitter and Facebook apps, they mark the last read location in the timeline (or at least, what was the top of the timeline when you refreshed) with a 'jagged cell' (rectangular cell, not too tall, top and bottom edges are jagged/sawtooth)

Is this a standard iOS feature or a 3rd party library/control, and does anyone know how to make use of it in my own apps?

Thanks in advance!

Glenn / alias